# Is there an equilent REST API Function to get the balance of an Paypal account ,similar to the NVP get balance API?

Tags: rest, api, paypal, nvp

Is there an equilent REST API Function to get the balance of an Paypal account ,similar to the NVP get balance API?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, this isn't really the place to ask if an API exists or not. PayPal's API is publicly documented [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/). If you're having trouble implementing something using their API though, feel free to ask another question :)  (if you do, be sure to let us know what you've tried and why it didn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The REST API doesn't include it yet, but you can use the classic [GetBalance API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetBalance_API_Operation_NVP/).

If you're working with PHP you can use [my class library](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) to get this done for you very easily.  [Here's a functional sample](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/GetBalance.php).