# How to retrieve from Client Buyer's Account his avaliable 'funds' or 'balance' on PayPal API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've just setup my PayFlow Service Manager with my admin settings and create a Sandbox Account to have a test environment. I was reading the docs and the SDK specifications, the samples code on Java...But I still can't find how to know how much funds available have the Client on his PayPal account, before execute a payment in my Site...
 I found something of the classic API (GetBalance). This request doesn't exists yet on the new REST API. I need to implement on Java code.
 Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: Am I enabled to have this permissions to see this confidencial information of each PayPal account...?

Comment: PHP solution based on Classic SOAP API:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341990/function-to-get-the-balance-of-an-paypal-account-through-rest-api